# Not understanding the While(True) loop - Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

Having a hard time figuring out how the while(True) function is supposed to be fitted in the code. Also no idea if that is the right thing to use as I am trying to loop the game until the computer or the user hits the desired amount of points ( which the user inputs as rounds in the beginning)

```
import random


def main():

print
print "----------------------------------"
print "Welcome to Rock, Paper, Sciccors! "
print "----------------------------------"


rounds = input("How many points to win?: ")

user_choice = input("Choose Rock = 1 , Paper = 2 or Sciccors = 3: ")

user_score = 0

computer_score = 0



if user_choice == 1:

   print "You chose Rock"

elif user_choice == 2:

   print "You chose Paper"

elif user_choice == 3:

   print "You chose Sciccors"

else:

   print " Wrong! Choose 1, 2 or 3!"



computer_choice = random.randrange(1, 4)


if computer_choice == 1:

   print "Computer chose Rock"

elif computer_choice == 2:

   print "Computer chose Paper"

elif computer_choice == 3:

   print "Computer chose Sciccors"


def checkResults(computer_choice, user_choice):

    checkResults = computer_choice - user_choice


    if computer_choice - user_choice == 0:

       print("Draw!")

       user_score += 1

       computer_score += 1

    elif computer_choice - user_choice == 1 or computer_choice - user_choice      == -2:

       print("Computer wins")

       computer_score += 1

    elif computer_choice - user_choice == -1 or computer_choice - user_choice == 2:

      print("You win!")

      user_score += 1


 print (" Computer {} , You {}" .format(computer_score, user_score))

while(True):

if computer_score == rounds or user_score == rounds:

    main()
else:
    break
```

Comment: Can you update your answer with code that can be run without syntax errors? Preferably removing a lot of empty lines too.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this a bit shorter:

```
while computer_score == rounds or user_score == rounds:

    ' Your code returning computer_score and user_score
```

Basically a `while True` is an infinite loop that can only be ended using a `break` statement or via keyboard interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

`while True:` is an infinite loop that can only be stopped via the command `break`. In your example, you have created a loop that will infinitely run the `main()` method (which you defined earlier, by saying `def main():`). The only time the loop will end is if you kill the process (i.e. using task manager on Windows), or if `computer_score` and `user_score` both become unequal to `rounds` (which is what your `else` statement is implying on the second to last line). When this happens, the program calls `break` which forcibly ends the loop immediately and moves on... to the end of the file (which then ends the program).

It should be noted that using a `while True ... break` loop is sometimes frowned upon by programmers, because it is not seen as "elegant". It is totally fine code to do, but another way to re-write the last few lines is the following:

```
while computer_score==rounds or user_score==rounds:
    main()
```

This achieves the same result by running the `while` loop until `computer_score` and `user_score` both do not equal `rounds`. At that point, the while loop ends itself cleanly and ends the program by getting to the end of the file.